# An issue for sub-word tokenization preprocessing transformer

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the same content as the post on stack exchange.

I'm stacked with executing **the sub-word tokenization preprocessing** to use transformer.

According to the tutorial on [the article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/12/ner-with-little-data-transformers-to-the-rescue/), I have executed the sample code.

However, one function was not defined properly and no hint to fix it on the article.

If you have any ideas to fix the code, could you help me?

### Error

```
     22  return X, y
     23 
---> 24 X_train, y_train = preprocess(train_samples)
     25 X_val, y_val = preprocess(val_samples)

     12 def preprocess(samples):
     13  tag_index = {tag: i for i, tag in enumerate(schema)}
---> 14  tokenized_samples = list(tqdm(map(tokenize_sample, samples)))
     15  max_len = max(map(len, tokenized_samples))
     16  X = np.zeros((len(samples), max_len), dtype=np.int32)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

### Code

This code is from [the article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/12/ner-with-little-data-transformers-to-the-rescue/) to build a model for named entity recognition using transformer.

```py
import numpy as np
import tqdm
 
def tokenize_sample(sample):
  seq = [
         (subtoken, tag)
         for token, tag in sample
         for subtoken in tokenizer(token)['input_ids'][1:-1]
         ]
  return [(3, 'O')] + seq + [(4, 'O')]

def preprocess(samples):
  tag_index = {tag: i for i, tag in enumerate(schema)}
  tokenized_samples = list(tqdm(map(tokenize_sample, samples)))
  max_len = max(map(len, tokenized_samples))
  X = np.zeros((len(samples), max_len), dtype=np.int32)
  y = np.zeros((len(samples), max_len), dtype=np.int32)
  for i, sentence in enumerate(tokenized_samples):
    for j, (subtoken_id, tag) in enumerate(sentence):
      X[i, j] = subtoken_id
      y[i,j] = tag_index[tag]
  return X, y

X_train, y_train = preprocess(train_samples)
X_val, y_val = preprocess(val_samples)
```

### What I tried

I checked that the function, tokenize_sample is executable with the below code.

However, I'm not sure how to insert it to the original code.

```
for sample in samples:
  print(tokenize_sample(sample))
```

Comment: why dont you remove tqdm ?, any example text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to usage of `tqdm` as a module (because it is imported `import tqdm`) as if it was `tqdm` class from this module (`import tqdm from tqdm`).

So, changing:

```
import tqdm
```

to:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

should fix the problem.